# React: Having trouble loading external data and passing it down to component after storing it in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props, react-component

So here's the situation: I have a quiz app, I want to load the questions from json-server and store them in Redux state.

Why error happens: The app crashes before useEffect can load the data, because I'm passing down the questions data as a prop

Here's my useEffect function that loads the data:

```js
useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/questions");
      const data = await res.json();
      setQuestions(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);
```

Here is how I bind the action creator:

```
  const { setQuestions } = bindActionCreators(
{ setQuestions: addQuestions },
dispatch
```

);

I have buttons that switch between the questions by changing the currentQuestionIndex. Then I pass down questions[currentQuestionIndex] as a prop and try to display it.

```js
      <Question questionObject={questions[currentQuestionIndex]}></Question>

      <div className="buttonsContainer">
        {" "}
        <Button text="Previous"></Button>
        <Button text="Start Over"></Button>
        <Button text="Next"></Button>
      </div>
```

The error:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'question')
Question
C:/Users/user/Desktop/Coding/quiz/quiz/src/components/Question.jsx:10
   7 |   };*/
   8 |   return (
   9 |     <div className="question">
> 10 |       <p>{questionObject["question"]}</p>
  11 |     </div>
  12 |   );
  13 | }
```

Comment: Could you share whats the crash error message?

Comment: I'll put it in the post

Comment: Your questionObject is undefined on the render time hence it crashes. Try  <p>{questionObject && questionObject["question"]}</p> and lets see if this will render

Comment: Yes, that works like charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your welcome. Have a great weekend!